# Validation of array when every item is different

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

```js
[
    {
    "bankId": 0,
    "companyId": 0,
    "accountName": "",
    "companyName": "",
    "name": "Enable Virtual Credit Card",
    "value": "false",
    "key": "VC_ENABLED"
  },
  {
    "promotionalImage": "um-0000002416.jpg",
    "logoImage": "um-0000002416.jpg",
    "address2": "Abanda, AL. 11111",
    "address1": "41",
    "customerId": "10002416",
    "company": "ABC",
    "value": "",
    "key": "UNITE"
  },
  {
    "name": "Invoice",
    "accountReceivableEmail": "",
    "value": "false",
    "key": "INVOICE",
    "accountPayableEmail": ""
  },
]
```

I have this kind of formik initial value structure.
How can I validate with yup?

I want to validate `bankId` from 1st array element
and then if I want to validate `customerId` from 2nd element of array whose value also depend on 'key' (true/false) which also 2nd element's (object's) part of same array

Comment: Hi Codeman and welcome to SO. Is the array always like this, with three objects that have these properties? Does Yup have any documentation on validating a structure like this? What are the solutions you have found with your research?

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl
Thanks for edit my question 
please add Yup word 
otherwise it will be confusing to others. It's a request
"Yup validation of array when every item is different"

Comment: @EmielZuurbier
https://github.com/jquense/yup

Comment: It's tagged with "yup", no need to put it in the title. You can explain it in the body of your question. Furthermore, why don't you post the yup schema validation code you should already have...